# Prevent flexbox with progressbar from growing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, flexbox

I have a page design with columns, it can have one, two or three columns.
Theses columns should have the same size.

For that I use flexbox, it is nice and allows me to add/remove my columns and let the browser handle the resizing of the columns' width.

Now I hit an issue when a text inside a column is larger that the column's width. The column grow and that break the uniformity of the design...

I built an MCVE:

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
}
.main > div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div role="progressbar" style="width: 70%"
           aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
           class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </p>
  </div>
  <div style="background: #00F;">TEST2</div>
</div>
```

The columns should have the same size
*How can I make so that the column don't get affected by the content width ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `flex: 1 0 auto` you can use `flex: 1` and that is `flex: 1 1 0` on firefox or `flex: 1 1 0%` on chrome.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.main > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div role="progressbar" style="width: 70%" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background: #00F;">TEST2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel so bad having played with all the `flex-{grow,shrink,basis}:` properties for an hour, but failed to found that...

Answer (score 1):

```
.main > div {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
}
```

will do the trick

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
}
.main > div {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div role="progressbar" style="width: 70%"
           aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
           class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </p>
  </div>
  <div style="background: #00F;">TEST2</div>
</div>
```